# playframework Uncompiled class while enhancing

Tags: playframework

for some reason my play eclipse app cannot run a bootstrap job and throws below exception.
it seems the Model class User is not compiled and stored in tmp/classes directory. i'm not sure what is wrong that makes my play eclipse app not correctly compiling and generating classes in dev mode.
any solution is much appreciated.

----UPDATE-------

below is the models.User class. this class seems to cause problems. each time i change the source code of this class then play can't compile and raise the error below.

----------models.User.java-------------------------

```java
package models;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

    import controllers.Secure;
    import controllers.Secure.Security;

    import models.deadbolt.RoleHolder;
    import play.data.binding.As;
    import play.data.validation.CheckWith;
    import play.data.validation.Email;
    import play.data.validation.Equals;
    import play.data.validation.Match;
    import play.data.validation.MinSize;
    import play.data.validation.Password;
    import play.data.validation.Required;
    import play.db.jpa.Model;
    import play.libs.Codec;
    import play.mvc.Scope.RenderArgs;
    import util.UniqueObjectCheck;

    @Entity
    public class User extends Model implements RoleHolder {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Required
        public String firstname;
        @Required
        public String lastname;

        public String gender;

        @As("yyyy")
        public Date dob;

        @ManyToOne
        public Country country;

        @Required
        @MinSize(8)
        @Match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$")
        @CheckWith(UniqueUserCheck.class)
        public String username;

        @Required
        @Equals("confirmPassword")
        @MinSize(8)
        @Password
        public String password;

        @Password
        public String confirmPassword;

        @Required
        @Email
        @Equals("confirmEmail")
        @CheckWith(UniqueEmailCheck.class)
        public String email;

        public String confirmEmail;

        public String passwordHash;

        public Boolean active;

        //@Required
        //@OneToMany (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        public UserRole role;


        /**
         * 
         */
        public User() {
            // init();
            //if(role == null)
                //role= new ArrayList<UserRole>();
        }

        public User(final String firstname, final String lastname,
                final String gendre, final Date yob, final Country country,
                final String username, final String password, final String email) {
            super();
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.gender = gendre;
            dob = yob;
            this.country = country;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;

            init();

        }

        public User(final String firstname, final String lastname,
                final String gendre, final Date yob, final Country country,
                final String username, final String password,
                final String confirmPassword, final String email,
                final String confirmEmail) {
            super();
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.gender = gendre;
            dob = yob;
            this.country = country;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
            this.email = email;
            this.confirmEmail = confirmEmail;

            init();
        }

        public User(final String email, final String password) {

            if (email == null || email.isEmpty())
                throw new RuntimeException("User must have an email");
            if (password == null || email.isEmpty())
                throw new RuntimeException("User must have a password");
            this.email = email;
            // init();

        }

        private void init() {
            passwordHash = Codec.hexMD5(password);

            // BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(saltFactor));

        }

        public void addRole(String name) {
            if(name == null || name.isEmpty())
                return;

            if(hasRole(name)){
                System.out.println( "user already has role: "+ name);
                return;

            }
            this.save();
            new UserRole(this,name).save();     
            this.save();
            System.out.println( "added user role: "+ name);

        }

        public void encodePassword(final String password) {

            passwordHash = Codec.hexMD5(password);
            // BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(saltFactor));

        }

        public boolean checkPassword(final String plainTextPassword) {
            // BCrypt.checkpw(plainTextPassword, passwordHash);
            //System.out.println(Codec.hexMD5(plainTextPassword));
            return Codec.hexMD5(plainTextPassword).equals(passwordHash);

        }

        public static User getUserByEmail(final String email) {
            return User.find("byEmail", email).first();
        }

        public static User getByUserName(String userName) {
            return find("byUserName", userName).first();
        }

        public List<? extends models.deadbolt.Role> getRoles() {

            List<UserRole> roles=UserRole.find("byUser", this).fetch();
            System.out.println("getRoles="+roles);
            return roles;
        }

        public boolean hasRole(final String name) {
            this.save();
            UserRole userRole=UserRole.getByName(name);
            List<UserRole> roles=UserRole.find("byUser", this).fetch();
            //System.out.print("userRole=");
            //System.out.println(userRole);
            return (roles.contains(userRole));


        }

        class UniqueEmailCheck extends UniqueObjectCheck<User> {
            @Override
            protected List loadExistingUniqueObjects(final User user) {
                setMessage("validation.emailUsed", user.email);
                return User.find("byEmail", user.email).fetch();

            }
        }

        class UniqueUserCheck extends UniqueObjectCheck<User> {
            @Override
            protected List loadExistingUniqueObjects(final User user) {
                setMessage("validation.used", user.username);
                return User.find("byUsername", user.username).fetch();
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.username;
        }

    }
```

------models.UserRole.java-------------------------

```java
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import models.deadbolt.Role;
import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.Model;

/**
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class UserRole extends Model implements Role {
    @Required
    public String name;
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    public UserRole(User user,String name) {
        this.user=user;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static UserRole getByName(String name) {
        return UserRole.find("byName", name).first();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

----------------Error Exception--------------------

```java
    Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer on Bootstrap

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@496614e7 on Bootstrap
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:511)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:165)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:84)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClasses.java:67)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:455)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader$getAssignableClasses.call(Unknown Source)
    at {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/types.tag.(line:3)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:379)
    at {module:crud}/conf/routes.(line:4)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:162)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:190)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:164)
    at play.mvc.Router.load(Router.java:48)
    at play.mvc.Router.detectChanges(Router.java:219)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer on Bootstrap
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:302)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:506)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:165)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:84)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClasses.java:67)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:455)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader$getAssignableClasses.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at Template_1001$_run_closure1.doCall(types.tag:6)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at Template_1001$_run_closure1.doCall(types.tag)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:277)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.access$300(GroovyCategorySupport.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.use(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:333)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$723.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
    at Template_1001.run(types.tag:2)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:362)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
    at Template_1000$_run_closure1.doCall(routes:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at Template_1000$_run_closure1.doCall(routes)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:273)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:277)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.access$300(GroovyCategorySupport.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.use(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:333)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$723.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
    at Template_1000.run(routes:2)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Error in PropertiesEnhancer
    at play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer$1.edit(PropertiesEnhancer.java:175)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:197)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.instrument(CtBehavior.java:618)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(PropertiesEnhancer.java:133)
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:297)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to visit uncompiled class while enhancing. Uncompiled class: models.User
    at play.classloading.enhancers.Enhancer$ApplicationClassesClasspath.openClassfile(Enhancer.java:75)
    at javassist.ClassPoolTail.openClassfile(ClassPoolTail.java:335)
    at javassist.ClassPool.openClassfile(ClassPool.java:594)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:185)
    at javassist.CtClassType.makeFieldCache(CtClassType.java:760)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getMembers(CtClassType.java:751)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredField2(CtClassType.java:873)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getField2(CtClassType.java:828)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getField(CtClassType.java:820)
    at javassist.expr.FieldAccess.getField(FieldAccess.java:113)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer$1.edit(PropertiesEnhancer.java:140)
    ... 89 more
```

Comment: In my experience, a "precompile" often give me much more clear exception messages than compile at run-time (of dev mode)

Comment: when i run play precompile i get this error: `
02:54:16,526 ERROR ~ Cannot start in PROD mode with errors
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:262)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:474)
 at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:278)
 at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:412)
 at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:566)
 at play.Play.init(Play.java:291)
 at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:158)`

Comment: can you provide the User class as this is what it seems to be having problems compiling.

Comment: @grahamrb : i updated post and included the models.user.java class which seems the one that raises these play compile problems. Hope you can help me overcome this annoying play issue.-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems i finally figured out the cause that makes my play app so fragile and giving random errors:

i was implementing the Registration process as a "play module". I used the registration module from book ["playframework cook book"](http://www.packtpub.com/play-framework-cookbook/book) (the source code of this module is included below this answer)

using this registration module seems to have made play unstable maybe because it conflicts with other play modules like crud module.
So the solution i removed the dependency for the above-mentioned registration module. and re-implement registration process in play controllers actions instead. after doing that i noticed the app becomes once again stable and i no more get these infernal errors.

the question why does the registration module described in book above make play so fragile and unstable? the src code of this registration module only makes use of two models classes User.java and Registration.java . maybe b/c User model is in someway tied to crud module this made play frequently confused and unstable? I still can't understand the real mechanism that made play be unstable when i added the above registration module to my dependencies.

But anyway the solution seems to be removing this custom module altogether .

```java
import play.Logger;
import play.Play;
import play.PlayPlugin;
import play.classloading.ApplicationClasses.ApplicationClass;

public class RegistrationPlugin extends PlayPlugin {
    private static boolean pluginActive = false;
    private static RegistrationService service;

    public void onApplicationStart() {
        ApplicationClass registrationService = Play.classes
                .getAssignableClasses(RegistrationService.class).get(0);
        if (registrationService == null) {
            Logger.error("Registration plugin disabled. No class implements RegistrationService interface");
        } else {
            try {
                service = (RegistrationService) registrationService.javaClass
                        .newInstance();
                pluginActive = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error(e,
                        "Registration plugin disabled. Error when creating new instance");
            }
        }
    }

    public void onEvent(String message, Object context) {
        boolean eventMatched = "JPASupport.objectPersisted".equals(message);
        if (pluginActive && eventMatched && service.isAllowedToExecute(context)) {
            service.createRegistration(context);
            service.triggerEmail(context);
        }
    }

    public static void confirm(Object uuid) {
        if (pluginActive) {
            service.confirm(uuid);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```java
 public interface RegistrationService {
        public void createRegistration(Object context);

        public void triggerEmail(Object context);

        public boolean isAllowedToExecute(Object context);

        public void confirm(Object context);
```

### }

```java
package service;


public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService {
    @Override
    public void createRegistration(Object context) {
        if (context instanceof User) {
            System.out.println("createRegistration() called");
            User user = (User) context;
            RegistrationSession r = new RegistrationSession();
            r.uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
            r.user = user;
            r.save();
            // System.out.println(RegistrationSession.findAll());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerEmail(Object context) {
        if (context instanceof User) {
            System.out.println("triggerEmail() called");
            User user = (User) context;
            RegistrationSession signUp = RegistrationSession.find("byUser",
                    user).first();

            MailNotifier.confirmation(signUp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAllowedToExecute(Object context) {
        if (context instanceof User) {
            System.out.println("isAllowedToExecute() called");
            User user = (User) context;
            return !user.active;

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void confirm(Object context) {
        if (context != null) {
            System.out.println("confirm() called");
            User user = null;
            final String email = Params.current().get("email");
            final String status = Params.current().get("status");

             /** System.out.print("status="); System.out.println(status);
             * System.out.println(context.toString());
             * System.out.print("Registration="); System.out.println(r);
             */
            RegistrationSession r = RegistrationSession.find("byUuid",
                    context.toString()).first();

            if (email == null || email.isEmpty() || status == null
                    || status.isEmpty()) {

                RenderArgs.current().put("activationFail",
                        "registration.activationFail");

            } else if (r == null && User.getUserByEmail(email) == null) {
                RenderArgs.current().put("activationFail",
                        "registration.activationFail");

            } else if (r == null && User.getUserByEmail(email) != null
                    && User.getUserByEmail(email).active) {
                RenderArgs.current().put("alreadyRegistered",
                        "registration.alreadyRegistered");

            }

            else if (r != null) {
                user = r.user;

                if (User.getUserByEmail(email) != null && !user.active
                        && status.equals("pending")) {
                    RenderArgs.current().put("pending", "registration.pending");
                    RenderArgs.current().put("email", user.email);

                } else if (User.getUserByEmail(email) != null && !user.active
                        && status.equals("confirm")) {
                    user.active = true;
                    user.save();
                    RenderArgs.current()
                            .put("verified", "registration.success");
                    // delete registration session object
                    r.delete();

                } else {
                    if (user != null && user.active) {

                        RenderArgs.current().put("alreadyRegistered",
                                "registration.alreadyRegistered");

                    } // todo : when should we make this confirm invalid?!

                    else if (user == null) {

                        RenderArgs.current().put("activationFail",
                                "registration.activationFail");

                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your code doesn't compile and that you are trying to start in prod mode.
Run **play eclipsify** in you project and reimport it in eclipse.
Resolve any possible compilation errors.
Also ensure the application is starting in dev mode **application.mode=dev** in your application.conf

Comment: i already did all the mentioned steps but still same problem!. It is strange as i didn't have this issue before .it started happening after i did some code change but i don't know what could be the source of problem. by looking to the exception trace can you locate some hint on the real cuase of the problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell. Have you added any plugins lately or changed JDK?

Comment: if you are using any modules also try to refresh your dependencies: **play deps --sync**

Comment: yes i tried play deps and all possible play options like play clean and play eclipsify ; yet same problem. i only use the crud module. it seems play while compiling the app got stuck in the CRUD.class the other .class are not compiled . but i can't figure out the real problem.

Comment: i updated post and included the models.user.java class which seems the one that raises these play compile problems. Hope you can help me overcome this annoying play issue.-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error after upgrading to 1.2.3 (from 1.2.2). 
to solve the problem, i did:

1. Eclipsify
2. Imported the project to eclipse
3. Corrected an error saing that "The method connected() from the type Secure.Security is not visible." (at the beginning i had no error)

then everything worked fine for me ...

Comment: i did the 2 first steps. when i import project to eclipse i have no errors. and when i run play app it is same error!. difficult to spot what's going wrong! any further help is much appreciated.